# Inverse $Z$-transform exercise problem

Tags: z-transform

I'm trying to solve a practice question about inverse $Z$ transform, and my solution is a bit different than the answer key. The question is just a simple polynomial expression

[image: simple polynomial expression]

My solution is as follows [image: is as follows]

But the textbook solution took a different approach as follows
[image: as follows]

I'm wondering if I did something wrong in my solution, or there could be multiple answers to the problem.